# if css(background-position) jquery conditional statement

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, conditional-statements

I am animating background image on my website by various amount of pixels depending on current position. I created an 'if' statement but it completely ignores the

```
if ($("#bg").css("background-position")
```

part, and is animating no matter what. Animation is working fine, even in Firefox, the problem is that the second condition is ignored and it always move by 670px. If i put into conditions other css value, like height for example, then it works.

```
$(function () {
    if ($("#bg").css("background-position") == "0px 0px") {
        $("#arrows .right").click(function(){
        $("#bg").animate({backgroundPosition:"-=670 0px"}, 4000);
        });  
    }
    else if ($("#bg").css("background-position") == "-670px 0px") {
        $("#arrows .right").click(function(){
        $("#bg").animate({backgroundPosition:"-=1000 0px"}, 4000);
        });  
    };
});
```

is background-position not working in a conditional statement at all?

I also try to change link depending on background position, this is completely ignored:

```
$(function () {
    if ($("#bg").css("background-position") == "-670px 0px") {
        $("#cafe a").attr("href", "http://mywebsite.com/about-us/") 
    }; 
});
```

Comment: Log `$("#bg").css("background-position")` to learn what happens.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It shows: 0px 0px, even if I click to animate and it moves to 670px. so this is the reason why it always moves by 670, it means then that it actually takes into account the condition, but doesn't 'write' new value into css?

Comment: I'm confused. Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: Me too :)
I have created it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kXQ99/7/
but it now doesn't work here, can't see why

Comment: Anyway, so the thing is that after seeing log, background-position is always 0,0 even when it animates to different x value, so I can't determine the next position and animate it further by another set of x values (new background position always depends on previous position) - so maybe there is easier way of achieveing that?

Comment: I haven't done much background animating, so I'm not really sure if this is still an issue you need to solve with a plugin, but that is what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/kXQ99/14/ I added the plugin at the top, because otherwise I would've had to upload and link it externally. Your code is at the bottom -- Oh and I tidied up your code a bit...

Comment: Thanks, this is great! it works exactly how I wanted. I am actually using this plugin already on my site, forgot to add it to fiddler :) 
Now I need to figure out how to add extra button to move left and right to different points of interest. 
Please add it as an answer so I can add you points (if this how it works here?).

Comment: With the code in that jsfiddle I liked, you can make another link so that you have `<a class="arrows left"></a> <a class="arrows right"></a>`. Then change the `id` to `class` in your javascript. Inside the click event you can put an if statement and ask: `if ( $(this).hasClass('left') ) { /* Left arrow was clicked */ } else { /* Right arrow must have been clicked, since there are only two arrows */ }`

Comment: Fantastic. How can I give you some points for the answer?
Is it possible to continuously animate that background, so when it reaches last position on the right - it then goes to the first point, but not by scrolling back to the left, but by still moving to the right? (I thought of repeating the bg but then I will have to have endless calculations of x positions....). Sorry for confusing it even more :)

Comment: Here's something I wrote a while back. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/J25dk/1 ? It works by animating the container by width of one image and when the animation ends it moves the first image to the last place, resets position to 0 and then loops that indefinitely. -- I can make an answer later, which you can choose as the right answer or just give a plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to mention these two things, since I never really tried to properly answer the question. I just kinda got around it.

---

**1.** The issue with your jsfiddle was that, well you forgot to add jquery in it... and  it did have actual code issue as well.

You expected value `-670px 0px` after the second click, but it actually gave this value `-670px 50%`. The first animation, I guess, switched 0 to 50% even though you didn't even try to animate `y`.

I'm not sure if it even should be analyzed, since I guess jquery doesn't natively support background position animation.

**2.** You said you had that plugin already in your website and I think the issue with that was that the plugin doesn't understand singular numerical value with `backgroundPosition`.

I took your original jsfiddle, added the plugin and added second value to the animate and it started working.

[jsfiddle of that](http://jsfiddle.net/kXQ99/24/)

---

The jsfiddle I gave you in the comments is basically identical to what I linked above, except it's just a little more compact.

[Jsfiddle of the compact working code](http://jsfiddle.net/kXQ99/14/)

Here's the compact working code with comments:

```
/* http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html
   Background position animation for jQuery v1.1.1.
   Written by Keith Wood (kbwood{at}iinet.com.au) November 2010.
   Available under the MIT (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt) license. 
   Please attribute the author if you use it. */
(function($){var g=!!$.Tween;if(g){$.Tween.propHooks['backgroundPosition']={get:function(a){return parseBackgroundPosition($(a.elem).css(a.prop))},set:setBackgroundPosition}}else{$.fx.step['backgroundPosition']=setBackgroundPosition};function parseBackgroundPosition(c){var d=(c||'').split(/ /);var e={center:'50%',left:'0%',right:'100%',top:'0%',bottom:'100%'};var f=function(a){var b=(e[d[a]]||d[a]||'50%').match(/^([+-]=)?([+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?)(.*)$/);d[a]=[b[1],parseFloat(b[2]),b[4]||'px']};if(d.length==1&&$.inArray(d[0],['top','bottom'])>-1){d[1]=d[0];d[0]='50%'}f(0);f(1);return d}function setBackgroundPosition(a){if(!a.set){initBackgroundPosition(a)}$(a.elem).css('background-position',((a.pos*(a.end[0][1]-a.start[0][1])+a.start[0][1])+a.end[0][2])+' '+((a.pos*(a.end[1][1]-a.start[1][1])+a.start[1][1])+a.end[1][2]))}function initBackgroundPosition(a){a.start=parseBackgroundPosition($(a.elem).css('backgroundPosition'));a.end=parseBackgroundPosition(a.end);for(var i=0;i<a.end.length;i++){if(a.end[i][0]){a.end[i][1]=a.start[i][1]+(a.end[i][0]=='-='?-1:+1)*a.end[i][1]}}a.set=true}})(jQuery);

// On document ready
$(function() {

    // When #arrows element is clicked...
    $("#arrows").on("click", function () {

            // Get the background position.
        var bgPos = $("#bg").css("background-position"),
                     // These two are ternary if statements..
                     // In human language these would be:
                     // if bgPos is equal to '0px 0px', use "-=670px 0px" OR....
                     // if bgPos is equal to '-670px 0px', use "-=1000px 0px"
            newPos = ( bgPos === '0px 0px' ) && "-=670px 0px" ||
                     ( bgPos === '-670px 0px' ) && "-=1000px 0px";

        // Console logs that help keep track of what is happening.
        console.log( 'Background position: ' + bgPos ); 
        console.log( 'If statement #1: ' + ( bgPos == '0px 0px' ) );
        console.log( 'If statement #2: ' + ( bgPos == '-670px 0px' ) );

        // Animate #bg...
        $("#bg").animate({
            backgroundPosition: newPos
        }, 4000);

    });

});
```